# How to make a POST request with multiple headers and a raw text body in Spring Boot REST?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, post, resttemplate

The body is in raw text format and the request is a POST method. I am using this code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/run", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<String> runReport(){

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String fooResourceUrl = "requestURL";

    String auth = "username:password";
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );

    // Defining the Headers
    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    headers.add("Authorization", authHeader);
    headers.add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=\"Boundary_1_1153447573_1465550731355\"");
    headers.add("Accept", "multipart/form-data");

    // Defining the Body
    String outputFormatType = "pdf";
    String body = "--Boundary_1_1153447573_1465550731355\n"
            +"Content-Type: application/json\n"             
            +"Content-Disposition: form-data;" + " "+"name=\"ReportRequest\"\n\n"

            +"{\"byPassCache\":true,\"flattenXML\":false,\"attributeFormat\":"+ "\""+outputFormatType+"\"" +"}\n"
            +"--Boundary_1_1153447573_1465550731355--";


    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);


    restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("username", "password"));
    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(fooResourceUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by removing the following line:

```
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("username", "password"));
```

As it was already being added in header. And added the body as a parameter to the HttpEntity constructor:

```
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
```